# robust bookmarking system in bash

Tags: bash, directory, bookmarks

Is there any bookmarking system available in `bash` that will allow me substitute aliases
for real directories?

I am familiar with `cdargs` and using `cdb`, `ca` etc for moving between directories.

I am thinking of a tool which allows me to type:

```
diff ./file openb(x)/file
```

where `openb(x)` will be a directory in the bookmark system that has been aliased to x
(so that `cdb x`, `cpb file x` etc all work).

Comment: `x=/path/2/dir/x ; y=/path/2/dir/y ; diff ./file $x/file ; cd $x ; cp file $x ... etc` ? The var assignments would be in your .bash_rc or other .rc file as you deem appropriate. I've used this sort of thing for years, and it seems good enough, and is portable. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the bookmarking system [bookmarks.sh](http://lug.fh-swf.de/shell/#bookmarks). From the README:

### SHELL VARIABLES

The command

```
bookmark -e
```

exports a shell variable from every existing and new bookmark.  Add this line
to `~/.bashrc` to use this feature permanently. For the bookmark

```
vm    '/home/vmware.shared-folders'
```

the variable `vm` will be exported. An already existing variable will not be overwritten. The variable can be used with shell commands, e.g.

```
diff ./file $vm/file
```

To export only one variable use e.g.

```
bookmark -e vm
```

### RESOLVE A BOOKMARK

To occasionally resolve a bookmark without exporting a variable use `bm`:

```
diff ./file `bm vm`/file
```

Please note the backticks: `bm` is a shell function.